# Setting openFileDialog to variable string

Tags: c++-cli, openfiledialog

I am trying to create a small GUI that will rename a file (eventually a batch of files). I am using C++ and Windows user (Visual Studio Community 2015).

I have a btnSelectFiles button with which I want to open a file selection GUI.

I am trying to use openFileDialog but am struggling to set the file name to a string variable.

The code I am using:

```
public:
void btnSelectFiles_Click(Object^ /*sender*/, System::EventArgs^ /*e*/)
{
    IO::Stream^ myStream;
    OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

    openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr)
        {
            // Insert code to read the stream here.
            myStream->Close();
        }
    }

    /*String test = openFileDialog1;*/
}
```

One of my many tries was to use:

```
String test = openFileDialog1
```

I also tried:

```
String test = openFileDialog1.FileName
```

But received an expression must have class type error.

Please can someone help me solve this and thus help my understanding on the matter. The book I have picked up does not cover this and I have struggled to find help online.

Comment: and [`openFileDialog1.FileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) doesnt work?

Comment: Visual Studio gives me an error, expression must have class type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using c++/CLI ( rather than C++ ) you must write

```
String^ test = new String( openFileDialog1.FileName );
```

Comment: This answer does not make sense to me. The FileName property returns a String, so there should be no need to create a new String. This should work:
    String^ test = openFileDialog1->FileName; or even auto test = openFileDialog1->FileName;